# Image path inside ref tag is not loading

Tags: html, angular

I am working in an Angular project ,In this I am binding the image path from API.
I receive the path from API and trying to display the images in a HTML page .In my case image path inside the src tag is loading well but image path in the ref path is not loading .

Image 1

```
<div class="row">
      <img id="sm001" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['0']['small_Images']}}" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" ref="bigImages['0']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm005" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['1']['small_Images']}}" alt="img2" class="img-thumbnail" ref="bigImages['1']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm002" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['2']['small_Images']}}" alt="img3" class="img-thumbnail" ref="bigImages['2']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm003" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['3']['small_Images']}}" alt="img4" class="img-thumbnail" ref="bigImages['3']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm004" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['4']['small_Images']}}" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" ref="bigImages['4']['big_Images']">
  </div>
```

As in the above code the src tag images are loading but the ref tag images are not loading.

When I put ref="{{bigImages['4']['big_Images']}}" like this the HTML page is not get loaded.

Actually what I am trying is when I hover on the small images (src images ) it will display the big images (ref images).
Please guide me to solve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `ref` you forgot to add `{{ }}` :

change

```
ref="bigImages['0']['big_Images']"
```

to :

```
ref="{{bigImages['0']['big_Images']}}"
// OR
[attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']" // I would suggest this
```

---

This one will might throw error as it not known property of img tag

```
ref="{{bigImages['0']['big_Images']}}"
```

So if you want any custom tag to any element , you should do it like

```
[attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']"
```

Comment: If I add ref="{{bigImages['0']['big_Images']}}" like this the HTML page is not get loaded

Comment: try `[attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']"` @Nikson

Comment: @Nikson , glad to know , Happy Coding BTW :)

Comment: Can you please explain about it for my knowledge

Comment: can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748925/adding-products-in-cart-carousel-generate-new-row-of-slider-in-angular4

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']"
```